# How to run the Protractor Spec for multiple times based on excel values

Tags: node.js, cucumber, protractor

I am new to Protractor. I have the test data stored in excel in multiple rows. I would like to run the same spec multiple times for each row in excel. Is it possible?

```
exports.config = {


    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    baseUrl: 'https:somewebsite.com',

    capabilities: {

        'browserName': (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || workbook.Sheets[sheetNamelist[sheetNumber]]['N2'].v)
        , 'version': (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_VERSION || 'ANY')
        , 'shardTestFiles': false
    , },
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    },

    framework: 'custom'
    , frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

    specs: [
    '../Features/Availity_Login.feature'
  ]
    , exclude: '../Features/database.feature'
    , cucumberOpts: {

        monochrome: true
        , strict: true
        , plugin: ["pretty"]
        , require: ['../StepDefinitions/*.js', '../Support/*.js']
        , tags: '@AllureScenario,@Regression,@ProtractorScenario,~@DatabaseTest' // @DatabaseTest scenario can be included when the username & password of DB have been configured in Support/database.js

    }


};
```

in the above script i would like to run the specs for more than once as I have multiple test data in my excel. I am able to read the excel values using the module 'xlsjs'. Looping through the spec will run the spec only for first time.

Comment: looks like you are using my `protractor-cucumber-allure` repo :)

Comment: since you are using `protractor-cucumber` i would suggest you to use data tables! for test data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing same functionality with multiple sets of data is nothing but ***Data Driven*** approach. For that we have ***jasmine-data-provider*** package, which will helps you in doing data driven testing with Protractor.

```
Code Snippet:

var using = require(‘jasmine-data-provider);
var loginData = require('../example/Test Data/Test.json');


describe('Data driven test spec', function () { 
   /*define sets of input data as array in method called arrayOfData*/
   //OR retrieve all test data and stored into array and the follow below    
   //approach

   function arrayOfData() {
   return [
          {
            "username": "admin",
            "passwordField": "admin"
          },

         {
          "username": "admin1",
          "passwordField": "admin2"
          }
      ]
    } /*below one will loop the test case based on data size and pass single  
       data set every time till complete the end of array*/

     using(arrayofData, function (inputData) {
      it('test case logic to be executed for each set of data', function ()                      
           {
           browser.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/login");
           element(by.model("username")).sendKeys(inputData.username);
           element(by.model("password")).sendKeys(inputData.passwordField); 
           element(by.buttonText("Authenticate")).click();
        });
    });
 });
```

**NOTE**: If jasmine-data-provider package NOT yet installed in your machine, please install it by running below command before going to run test script.

```
npm install jasmine-data-provider
```

Comment: To expand a little on this answer, there is a great tutorial for getting set up with this: http://moduscreate.com/protractor-and-jasmine-data-provider-write-once-test-many/

Comment: @Mallory thank you very much for sharing such a good article.

Comment: Hi Suresh/Mallory ...Thanks for the tutorial. But it doesn't tell how to get the data from excel.

Comment: @rajasekaranrj read data from excel and store into an array of objects like format i have shown in example - [ {
            "username": "admin",
            "passwordField": "admin"
          },

         {
          "username": "admin1",
          "passwordField": "admin2"
          }
      ]

And use it on login spec

Comment: Hi Suresh.. It sounds good. Since I am new to Protractor , could you please let me know the way/steps to accomplish it.

Comment: add my skype id 'sallojusuresh' @rajasekaranrj

Comment: Hi Suresh.. Thank you so much. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are already using `protractor-cucumber-framework`. Cucumber provides you ways to run same test on multiple data. You don't need to add complexity of reading data from excel. Reuse the capabilities provided by the framework. For example, in your .feature file you can do something like below. So this scenario will run for every row as a separate test

```
 Scenario Outline:
    Given I have "<firstNumber>" and "<secondNumber>"
    When I add them together
    Then the total is "<sum>"

    Scenarios:
      | firstNumber | secondNumber | sum |
      | 5           | 7            | 12  |
      | -5          | 7            | 2   |
      | 5           | -7           | -2  |
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh. This is our client Requirement. They will update the test data in excel and protractor should take the value from excel.